# Control/variable naming conventions in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, naming-conventions

I think the main distinction in naming is between **logic** and **view-related** objects. You might have a variable named “**UserName**” in the code behind file of a page, but then also a .NET TextBox in which a user is supposed to enter their username (a sensible ID would also be “**UserName**”). How can we differentiate (ID-wise), between the logic “**UserName**” and the view “**UserName**”. My question is, what is a sensible distinction to make when coming up with these names?

In my opinion, a variable name/control ID should never describe what it IS, only what it DOES. “**tbUserName**” describes that it is a TextBox, “**strUserName**” defines that it is a string.

One idea would be to prefix all view related objects with “**vwUserName**” and keep the logic part as “**UserName**”. Does that make sense? What about when we have a situation where you have validators? Would you name them “**vwUserNameRequiredValidator**”, or “**vwEmailAddressFormatValidator**”? In that situation would you need to describe what it actually is? Would you give a .NET RequiredFieldValidator object an ID of “**rfvUserName**”?

I really want to get an idea of what other people think on this, because I want to come up with a sensible and consistent naming convention system going forward. I’m interesting to hear arguments for any type of system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hungarian notation is so 1990s... ;-)

I would use UserName for logic and userName for id.

Comment: So UserName for logic, _UserName for private logic (maybe) and userName for an ID? Seems like it could get confusing if you are using intellisense, especially to a developer unfamiliar with your naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use **_userName** as a variable and **UserName** as property in code behind, and as ID for a text box **UserNameField**. I find it easier to work with the intellisense in this way, instead of prefixing as we did in the VB-days with txtUserName.

Edit: not calling it UserNameTextBox, but UserNameField is also easier to work with if you want to the exchange the field (that is TextBox) to another control (it may not apply to this example of username though.

Comment: What about for a RequiredFieldValidator?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it: I'd go for **UserNameRequiredValidator**.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. What about if you had a RegularExpressionValidator that checked whether a UserName contained at least 2 numbers and a non-alphanumeric symbol?

Comment: Hmm, good question... I guess that's where I stop being consistent :) But right now, I'd name it: **UserNameFormatValidator**. That way, I could exchange it for a custom validator later if needed.

Comment: I actually completely agree with you. I'm just trying to justify it and convince a few other people. :). My justification is that you are naming based on what it DOES, rather than what it IS. I think that's the proper way to name things.

Answer (score 1):

**For controls**, I always add a prefix like:

> Textbox - txtName - I don't use tb because it can be confusing since I use tbl for HtmlTable
>
> Checkbox - cbIsNameRequired
>
> RequiredFieldValidator - rfvName

**For variables:**

> Name
>
> IsNameRequired

etc..

It is all about getting used to a pattern but always have a pattern..

Comment: What about if the TextBox had to become something else? All your references in the code behind would refer to something of the type "txt".

Comment: Yes. Thats why I send a thank you email to MS for find & replace all when I face with that situation

Comment: This seems to be common practice in asp.net webforms

Comment: @Jimmy - Mailing MS for find & replace? Just kidding :)

Comment: This seems wasteful though. What's the advantage of doing that, rather than making it more generic so you don't end up having to find/replace a load of stuff? It's the same thing as prefixing strings with "str" or "s".

Comment: The advantage is, you type txt and you see all your textboxes :) you type cb and you see your checkboxes. That is why I prefer this naming convention yet you can use anything that you want or you feel that is right.

Comment: Yup,I don't see why you're getting downvoted as this is how many texts and tutorials name their controls